# Vlookup using date

Tags: excel, vba

I have defined last row and worksheet, so these are fine. The problem seems to be with the `Vlookup` function itself. I keep getting the error.

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
        DateSerial(VBA.Left(Curent_F_FileWs.Range("CR" & 214), 4).value, 
        VBA.Mid(Curent_F_FileWs.Range("CR" & 214), 6, 2).value,                         
        VBA.Mid(Curent_F_FileWs.Range("CR" & 214).value, 9, 2)), 
        CPI_FileWs.Range("A2:G" & CPI_File_LR), 7, False)
```

The error:

```
"Unable to get Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class"
```

Comment: Is it wirtten like that? Seems to be missing a few **_** underscores. Shouldn't give you that error though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error when Vlookup does not find a match. You must know that Excel keeps the date as a Long... Please, try the next variant:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
        CLng(DateSerial(VBA.Left(Curent_F_FileWs.Range("CR" & 214), 4).value, _
        VBA.Mid(Curent_F_FileWs.Range("CR" & 214), 6, 2).value, _                         
        VBA.Mid(Curent_F_FileWs.Range("CR" & 214).value, 9, 2))), _
        CPI_FileWs.Range("A2:G" & CPI_File_LR), 7, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `Application.Vlookup` instead of worksheetfunction because when it does not find a match it doesn't fail catastrophically.
It just returns an error to the variable to make sure the variable is a variant.

You can use this if it finds a value `if not error(variable) then`